# conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint with .net UserProfile class (conflicting multiplicities)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, constraints, one-to-one

I have .net UserProfile class

```
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public Person Person {get; set;}
}
```

And my own class Person

```
public class Person
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("UserProfile")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    // (...) another properties 

    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to connect them one-to-one, where in UserProfile Person is optional. 
When I try to do 'update-database', I get:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.People_dbo.UserProfile_Id". The conflict occurred in database "CyberShop.CyberShopDb", table "dbo.UserProfile", column 'UserId'.
```

So, I try to do this via Fluent API in that way:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile>()
        .HasOptional(zm => zm.Profile);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Profile>()
        .HasKey(zmt => zmt.UserId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Profile>()
        .HasRequired(zmt => zmt.UserProfile)
        .WithRequiredDependent(zm => zm.Profile);
```

And then I get:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The navigation property 'Person' declared on type 'CyberShop.Models.UserProfile' has been configured with conflicting multiplicities.
```

What am I still doing wrong?

### Solution

I don't exactly understand why, but when I've marked Person as Required with annotation (
completely without Fluent API)- problem solved.

```
public class UserProfile
{
  // (...)

  [Required]
  public Person Person {get; set;}
}
```